# Determine the total memory allowed to be used by my process

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, out-of-memory

There's probably 20 (or more?) of these questions on stackoverflow, but none of them address what I'm trying to do.

I have an application whose purpose is to receive some data from an outside source through a web service, normalize it and then populate it into a `BlockingCollection<T>`, to be consumed at a later time when a connection to another web service can be made. The code to receive the data looks like this (it's a Nancy callback):

```
private dynamic AcceptSignalData(dynamic parameters)
{
    try
    {
        //This call extracts the post body data from the web request. 
        //The post body data contains JSON of the changed signals
        var states = this.Bind< List< SignalStateData > >();

        this._logger.Log(LogSeverity.Debug, string.Format("Received {0} states", states.Count));

        foreach (var state in states.Select(s => new SignalStateData(s.Id, s.Value, s.Timestamp.ToUniversalTime())))
        {
            this._collection.Add(state);
        }
        return this.Response.AsJson(true);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this._logger.Log(LogSeverity.Error, "An error was thrown while extracting received data. The error is as follows:");
        this._logger.Log(LogSeverity.Error, ex);
    }
    return this.Response.AsJson(false);
}
```

In this case, `this._collection` is consumed if a connection to the other web service can be made.

A requirement of this is: if the connection cannot be made, the application should simply hold on to the data in `this._collection` until the cows come home and dispatch when the connection is there. Obviously if it waits to long the application will throw an `OutOfMemoryException` which is the problem I'm running into.

I'm trying to determine the point at which the `OutOfMemoryException` will actually occur so I can simply drop the *n* oldest items from `this._collection`. I want to find, as a rough percentage, how much memory my process has remaining.

I've used the code from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13369196/386703) but from my understanding, that's the total memory available in the system, which isn't all that useful for my purpose. This is the code I have now, but it produces negative numbers because of the system-wide scope of `PerformanceCounter`:

```
/// <summary>
/// The constructor for the <see cref="MemoryManager" /> object.
/// </summary>
public MemoryManager(ILogger logger)
{

    this._memoryCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available Bytes");
    this._memoryCancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    this._updateMemoryTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(this.UpdateAvailableMemory, this._memoryCancellationToken.Token);
    this._currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    this._logger = logger;

    this.AvailableMemoryPercentage = 100.0F;
}

#endregion
#region Methods

private async void UpdateAvailableMemory(object state)
{
    var token = (CancellationToken)state;

    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {

            float totalAvailableBytes = this._memoryCounter.NextValue();

            float totalUsedBytes = totalAvailableBytes - this._currentProcess.PrivateMemorySize64;

            this.AvailableMemoryPercentage = Math.Round(totalUsedBytes / totalAvailableBytes * 100, 2);

            var logMessage = string.Format("RAM: {0} MB ({1}%)",
                                (1.0 * totalUsedBytes / 1024 / 1024).ToString("0.##"),
                                this.AvailableMemoryPercentage);

            this._logger.Log(LogSeverity.Info, logMessage);

            await Task.Delay(MEMORYCHECKINTERVAL_MS, token);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._logger.Log(LogSeverity.Debug, "Exception in memory management:");
            this._logger.Log(LogSeverity.Debug, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't care how much memory my process is using (well, I guess I do but it's only 50% of the problem); I'm more interested in how much is available. I understand that there's a lot of different angles to this but I'm looking for a *very* rough estimate.

Comment: on x86 2Gb, on x64 all the free ram

Comment: Pedantic correction to @Gusman comment - Since OOM mainly caused by exhastion of address space on x86 -you have 2/3/4GB (depending on OS/large-address-aware flag for app), on x64 - almost unlimited (page file will limit really available memory)

Comment: Can I ask are you really sure you would want your `BlockingCollection` taking up as much RAM as possible? Have you thought about setting a limit on how many items you add before you start removing from the end, or having items timeout? I understand you may wish to track how much memory you are using but I wouldn't think you should try mapping the size of the collection to the amount of memory you application is current taking up.

Comment: @StephenRoss Obviously there's other things in my application that take up memory. The `BlockingCollection` just happens to be the largest at any given time due to the amount of items coming from the web service. Over a day or two, it's into the billions. The memory code in my question is not mapped specifically to the `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: @Gusman I just tested the application in question while watching memory usage. I got the `OutOfMemoryException` at 1.5GB used. I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate x64. I have 16gb of RAM.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this can be by memory fragmentation, maybe some blocks of ram are being allocated but not fully used. Also, having a list so big in memory is usually not a good design, use an storage buffer (a file, a db or something like that) and process just blocks of data.